# Chomsky Normal Form for context free grammars ambiguous/unambiguous properties?

Tags: context-free, discrete-mathematics, ambiguity, normal-forms, theory

My textbook states:

> Finally, it must be stressed that the Chomsky normal form says nothing about ambiguity in general—a CFG in Chomsky normal form may or may not be ambiguous, just like we have for arbitrary CFGs. On the other hand, if you start with an unambiguous CFG and perform the conversion described above, the resulting CFG in Chomsky normal form will still be unambiguous.

I don't really get this. Why does an unambiguous CFG when converted to Chomsky normal form always yield unambiguous CFG? Is it possible for an ambiguous expression to become unambiguous when converting it to Chomsky normal form?

If someone could explain I would appreciate it.

Comment: Welcome to ComputerScience@SE.

Comment: (You could try and prove that *the conversion described above* does not make ambiguity disappear. Or show one case where it does.)

Comment: It all depends on the constructions. The rules for shortening productions like $A\to ABCD$ just change the derivation trees, so will not effect ambiguity. Removing chain rules $A\to B$ however might as an effect also remove cycles, and thus may solve ambiguity in some simple examples.